# Load string array from database

Tags: java, database, deserialization

What's easiest way to load address field content into a string array from a Postgres database:

```
id   | name            | address
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1    | John            | {"line1","line2","line3"} 
2    | Steve           | {"addr1","addr2","addr3"} 



String[0] = "line1"
String[1] = "line2"
String[2] = "line3"
```

I'm not sure if this is a serialized string array but somehow i'm failing on this simple task.

Comment: What is the type of the `address` column?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oh shoot, right you are! (misread the braces as square brackets)

Comment: Try this:-  while (rs.next()) {
   String[] addressArray = rs.getString("address").split(",");
  }

Comment: working with a postgres database, the fields is of type
character varying(45)[]

Comment: Try `String[] addressArray = (String[]) rs.getArray("address").getArray();`

Comment: Thanks for your comment saka1029!! worked perfectly fine!!